# What is the maximum length of a chat room message?

Tags: support, chat, character-limit

On tex.stackexchange, I had to break a chat message into pieces because it was too long. Comment fields on the list itself say how many characters are left, but chat messages don't, and I can't find information on their size. (I probably just don't know where to look.)

Chat messages do seem to be smaller than comments, and a friendly co-member of meta.tex.stackexchange [confirmed this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2172/5763) by actually counting what he typed in (about 600 for comments vs. 500 for a chat message).  Since the reason for my being in the chat room was in answer to a request to divert "extended comments" to a chat, I find that request rather impertinent.

A clear indication of the permissible size of a message, or a count-down a la comment, or even both, would be very welcome.  It would also be welcome to have a message size that is at least no smaller than that of a comment in the main list.

Comment: It is 500 (I don't think it's documented anywhere, though), but I don't know the reason for the use of a "Whoops, too long!" message versus the countdown. Perhaps to save screen real estate without being annoying.

Comment: @Tim this is indeed 500, maybe time to post this as answer? :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The limit of a normal single line message in chat is 500 characters.

[image: single line limit]

If you enter an explicit line-break (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> on a Windows machine) you can lift this limit of 500 characters.

[image: more then 500 characters]

but in the transcript you'll still see only 500 characters. Users would have to click the *See full text* link to see the complete message:

[image: larger then 500 messages]

I didn't test the actual maximum allowed size of a multi-line chat message but I wouldn't be surprised if it is 30,000 characters, similar to what it is for posts. If you are lucky (which it turns out [we are](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6151455#6151455)) it is `nvarchar(max)` in the database, allowing for [1 billion characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11131977/578411) ... In which case you could technically backup your harddrive in a chatroom ...

It is true that comments on posts can be longer, they are capped at 600 characters. However, when comments are moved to a chatroom, they are not hindered by the 500 characters single line restriction. [Here is an example of an 557 characters imported message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35361418#35361418)

Comment: i'll accept the answer, and appreciate the extra information on how to go to a second line.  but i'll have to check again on whether the limit on comments diverted to a chat for tex.stackexchange are (still?) capped at 500 characters -- i wouldn't have asked about this if i hadn't been interrupted at a length less than allowed in a comment on the main site.  (i agree that comments imported to a chat aren't truncated.  i was asking about new comments.)

Comment: Yeah, the 500 chars limit is the same for normal rooms or for rooms that are created due to an comment import.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@lyxal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/391137/lyxal)’s efforts, we found out that the practical limit for multiline messages (where it actually gets sent with no time out) is [about 4 million](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64124831#64124831).

Comment: If the error is timeout it means you are just testing your upload speed. It's impressive, but not relevant for what's being asked.