# Why is there a limit to the length of a message in chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

Used chat for the very first time. Typed a response that I thought was thoughtful, thorough, on topic etc. Clicked send. `This message is too long.` No indication of how short I needed to make it. Is it a little bit of careful editing? Or would I have to butcher the message? I don't know. And it is not worth it to find out.

1. Why is there a limit at all?
2. What is the limit? How was it chosen?
3. Can we get an indication, like on comments on the main sites, on how we are doing with respect to the limit.

Context for those curious:

The chat is https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31895/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-miller-how-did-this-day-trader-lose-so-much

My attempted comment:

> @ACD, "only putting in what you can afford to lose in the account"
> When one use margin one can lose more than one put in the account.
> Margin is the term used for borrowing from the brokerage to invest. A
> loan. Usually it's done for buying. Deposit $75,000 with the
> brokerage. Borrow $25,000. Buy $100,000 in stocks. If it goes down to
> zero, you are out the $100,000. And like all lenders the brokerage
> expects to get paid. Short selling **always** involves margin, because
> to sell a stock you don't own you have to borrow it first. If the
> stock goes up to much at the point it is bought back, that borrowing
> in stock is converted to borrowing in money, and again like any
> lender, the brokerage wants to get paid. Setting up a margin account
> is going to involve entering into a contract where one agrees to pay
> what is owed.

Comment: I would imagine this is to avoid a 'wall of text'

Comment: If you need to write a large chunk of text, you can always split your response between multiple messages. Consecutive messages from a user are grouped together, so the username and time stamp etc so not break up the flow.

Comment: Also, most chat rooms are a whole lot more informal than the Q&A sites (it depends on the room/site, have a quick read and check out the culture first), so long chunks of text are generally not needed. That's probably why there is a limit.

Comment: related feature request to get the limit of 500 chars raised: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267407/increase-number-of-characters-in-chat

Comment: Notice that making a multi-line message (add a line break) already allows you to post more

Answer (score 3):

- Why is there a limit at all?

Without limits it would be much harder to come up with a suitable storage scheme that balances performance, cost and functionality. That is not only relevant for the SE network but for all readers in that chatroom as well.  Users on a low bandwidth connection might run into connection issues if they have to download large messages.

- What is the limit? How was it chosen?

500 characters for a normal message. [1 billion characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297928/158100) for mulit-line message (shift+enter in the messagebox) but that lifted limited comes at the price of no more markdown. And the readers in the chatroom have to click the read more link to load the complete message (initially it shows 500 characters). How it was chosen can only be answered by the devs but looking at the [database schema](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/726880) my guess is it was at the top end of reasonable lengths. You could only argue it should have matched the limit of comments as is advocated for in [Increase number of characters in Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267407/increase-number-of-characters-in-chat).

- Can we get an indication, like on comments on the main sites, on how we are doing with respect to the limit.

That would be an awesome userscript but so far [no one have created one](https://stackapps.com/search?q=chat+is%3Aq). If you expect this to be created by the SE dev team you'll have to post a feature request and allow for many 6 to 8 weeks to have it implemented.